# VFR rendering of colors is too intense (VFR reader / iOS)

Tags: ios, pdf, vfr-reader

The VFR PDF rendering of my PDFs appears to be saturating colors far more compared to other PDF renderers Ive compared to. All colors (greens, blues etc) are "glowing".

Is there any way of adjusting the color rendering in the VFR toolkit?

Here are two examples:

VFR:

[image]

vs

Preview/Firefox/Chrome:

[image]

Edit:

So it looks like Im seeing a common (?) problem with rendering CMYK PDFs in RGB space which is what the underling CG layer is doing. I couldn't see any good solutions for converting the PDF to the RGB color space on the fly (or once they are downloaded to the phone)